# Computer PCIE slot power in parallel with external power supply?

Tags: power-supply, computer-architecture

I have an output card for my computer it is in the PCIe slot of the PC.  From there it goes to a break out box.  Where Pins 1 and 50 are power (5v) and 49 and 99 are ground.  If i turn on alot of the pins on the card at once, there is not enough amps to power everything.

Can i take an outside 5v power supply and can connect it in parallel with the 5vs coming out of the break out box/output card?

Comment: This seems like a legitimate question to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No, think about it for a minute. Lets say that your PC supply is exactly equal to the voltage of the external supply. Unless the PCI card has separate Vcc's you are effectively connecting the PC supply to the external supply, if the voltages are exactly the same, then no current will flow between the supplies an you'll be fine and you can parallel the supplies. This works in an ideal case.
(You also need to connect the grounds together.)

However, in the real world the supplies are not equal, source resistance (including cable resistance) will create an imbalance in voltages. Lets say one is 5.05V and the other is 5.15V. You'll get current transfer between the supplies based on the resistance between them. If the cables and source resistance is under an 1/10 ohm (which isn't unreasonable) then you'll have 0.1V/0.1Ω = 1A (as an example) and one power supply will be dissipating power in the other and that is bad.

So the answer is no, unless you have some way to match the voltage exactly (if you had an external control pin to regulate the voltage or the supply had some kind of control loop then this would work) OR if the Vcc's are seperated then the answer is yes.

Comment: OF course you are wrong about dissipating power. Computer power supplies do NOT accept a lot power from output to dissipate. If it has 5,15V on output, that is supposed to have 5,05 V, it will only consume power from sensing output voltage from 5,05V line.

Comment: Go grab to bench top supplies and set them to different voltages, connect them together and watch what happens. Be careful

Comment: Voltage Spike, I tried that with 2 USB phone chargers ( 5V 2A each ) to power 2,4A load. Of course it worked as expected and nothing broke down. Also I just connected 2 "19V 90W" laptop power adapters in paralell. one of them is 19,05V on the meter, anouther is 19,3V on the same meter. Current was measured at 10mA. NOT 1A, not 100mA, but 10mA. Multimeter shunt and multimeter cables are around 1,6 Ohms and power supplies cables onder 0,1Ohms each. 10mA*(1.6Ohms+2*0,1 Ohms)=18mV, NOT 19,3V-19,05V=250mV.

Comment: Did you measure the power being dissipated in each supply while you did this?

Comment: Voltage Spike, no i only put a finger on it to ensure nothing were overheating. It looks like all the temps were where I expected them to be

Comment: Oh, one other thing power supplies are parallelizable if they are isolated

Comment: Computer power supplies must be isolated to avoid making touching computer itself deadly. Does that make tham paralizeable - it depends on exact schematics, output cables and output voltage tolerance

Comment: They must be isolated on the DC side not the AC side, meaning that the DC to DC controllers must be isolated